# New relic track requests from mobile devices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, newrelic

I am using newrelic_rpm gem on heroku.
How to configure newrelic_rpm gem to track requests from mobile devices. Now newrelic tracks our api requests only from web browsers, but not from android and ios apps.

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem - in rails application i am using ActionController::Metal instead of ApplicaitonController. And for Metal controller should use this https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/adding-instrumentation-to-actioncontroller-metal

Answer (score 0):

New Relic tracks everything at a server level so you should be seeing analytics for everything, regardless of source.

The exception to this is the front end analytics which NR manages via JS injection - I don't believe that this functionality supports Mobile.

Comment: I found my problem - in rails application i am using  ActionController::Metal instead of ApplicaitonController. And for Metal controller should use this https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/adding-instrumentation-to-actioncontroller-metal

Comment: The Real User Monitoring feature does support mobile browsers. It uses JS injection, not SQL injection =)